# AWS Federated Login: (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRoleWithSAML operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

When I try to login using federated login for AWS CLI, I get this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRoleWithSAML operation: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML
```

This prevents me from logging into AWS CLI, and I need that so I can access our CodeCommit repo.

How should I fix this error, do I need to specify the role explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I did need to specify the role explicitly, by its ARN.

```
aws_cli_login --role arn:aws:iam::28475767868:role/my-role
```

It worked after that. Probably when I didn't specify a role it tried some default role for which I didn't have access.